# Jquery submit form error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which I want to submit upon button click which is outside the form, here is my HTML :

```
<form id="checkin" name="checkin" id="checkin" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" tabindex="100" class="identifier" name="identifier" id="identifier">
    <input type="submit" tabindex="101" value="Submito" class="elsubmito" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my jQuery :

```
$("button").live('click', function() {
    $("#checkin").submit();
});

$("#checkin").live('submit', function() {

});
```

When I click submit button inside the form its submitting ok, but its not submitting when I click on the button which is outside the form tags, why? how can I fix this ?

Comment: Could you show the markup defining the button outside the form?

Comment: There is a typo in the form tag - was it a copy/paste error or is it in your HTML too? (The action#" bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting all the `<button>` elements but you are trying to select an `<input>`.

It works when it is inside the form because the the normal submit functionality runs.

Change the selector to match the element you actually have: `input[type=submit]`

Better yet, forget about the JS and just structure your HTML better so that the submit button is inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you're handling the form processing using JavaScript, then you'll want to return `false` in your `button` and `form` processing code.

I was able to achieve identical results using the JavaScript below, and the two HTML examples (with the `button` inside and outside of the `form` element).

## JavaScript/jQuery

```
    $("button").live('click', function() {
        $("#checkin").submit();
        return false;
    });

    $("#checkin").live('submit', function(){
        alert("Hello world!");
        return false;
    });
```

## HTML Example 1

Button inside the form.

```
<form id="checkin" name="checkin" id="checkin" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" tabindex="100" class="identifier" name="identifier" id="identifier">
    <input type="submit" tabindex="101" value="Submito" class="elsubmito" name="submit">
    <button>test</button>
</form>
```

## HTML Example 2

Button outside the form.

```
<form id="checkin" name="checkin" id="checkin" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" tabindex="100" class="identifier" name="identifier" id="identifier">
    <input type="submit" tabindex="101" value="Submito" class="elsubmito" name="submit">

</form>

<button>test</button>
```

As I said, both examples performed as expected. You may want to double-check your `button` listening code to ensure that you are in fact using the `button` element. If you're using an element with the `id` attribute set to `button`, then you'll want to ensure you are using the proper jQuery selector:

```
$("#button").live('click', function() { // ...
```

Comment: @Bauer I want a page to reload .. I don't want it submitted asynchronously, mine script alerts something when form is posted as well but page doesn't go to the action url

Answer (score -2):

you can have a simple hyperlink outside of your form like this
`<a href="javascript: $('form checkin').submit()"> click to submit </a>` 
and that's all you need

Comment: This doesn't deal with the problem (assuming that the question was relating to using the HTML5 button element) and is considered bad practise (by some) since you are mixing markup with logic, when this can easily be achieved using event listeners.